# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET returning Async including object child collections

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am building a net core stack and implementing the layers as async.

I have the following customer repository code that is called by a web api layer

```
 public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    //interface this up
    private DbContextOptionsBuilder<SykesTestContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SykesTestContext>();
    public CustomerRepository(string connection)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
    }
    public async Task<List<Dom.Customer>> GetAll()
    {
        List<Dom.Customer> customers = new List<Dom.Customer>();
        var efCustomers = new List<Ef.Customer>();

        using (var customerContext = new TestContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
        {
            efCustomers = await customerContext.Customer
                                   .Include(cust => cust.Address)
                                   .Include(cust => cust.Telephone)
                                   .ToListAsync();

            foreach (var customer in efCustomers)
            {
                customers.Add(Mapper.Map<Ef.Customer, Dom.Customer>(customer));
            }
        }

        return customers;
    }


}
```

THE API Calling method

```
 [Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Customers")]
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;
    public CustomersController(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public async Task<List<Customer>> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var customers = await _customerRepository.GetAll();
            return customers;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out the "includes" then it all works fine.

If I use the includes (to build the object child collections) I get the following error in the browser: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET and only part of the json object is returned?

Any ideas?

```
 public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Address = new HashSet<Address>();
        Telephone = new HashSet<Telephone>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? ExternalId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Telephone> Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

Domain Model

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? ExternalId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Telephone> Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us your Ef.Customer & Dom.Customer models, and the server side exception details.

Comment: I don't think the models have any relevance here as this all works fine if I step through it. There is no exception stepping through it, only when I run the web api. There is no exception in the web api, only in the browser (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

Comment: Then the problem is not with EF `Include`s - when you comment them out, you just get empty collections.

Comment: yeah i get empty collections when i comment them out... which made me think my async stack was working and maybe it was something to do with async and eager loading!?!

Comment: if i make everything synchronous I get the same error... which i wasn't expecting

Comment: I have also taken out the object mapping so i just return the EF collection back up the stack and I get the same issue

Comment: ok, so: 

1. Debug C# code and see what is returned by customers - if you don't have any exception then here should be a valid model with all data? 

2. See in browser 'Developer tools' in 'Network' tab what you receiving from the server - if data was sent then you will see there a nice preview of JSON data.

Comment: Another thing - why you are using HashSet? I never used it to return data from WebApi (JSON) - maybe try to change it to List<>, then change properties in the model to IEnumerable or IList - just for test?

Comment: if i step through it everything is populated correctly, which i REALLY don't get!... hashset is what EF generates... i have already changed this to list as I though this might be a problem.... i'm running the API directly from visual studio and it returns the first customer with an address (there should be 3 customers with 1 address and telephone each)... then it hangs with the disconnect error... if i comment out the address include I get the first customer with its telephone!!

Comment: the api method has the 3 three full objects returned, the browser just the 1st object!

Comment: i also sometimes get "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json" in dev tools

Comment: I've got it: There was some sort of circular reference in the child collection i.e. Address had a Customer property... once i get rid of this it works! doh ... the classes are just copies of the EF classes , which is where this is auto generated... I'll need to have a think about this... thanks for your effort

Comment: I can't repeat it often enough: **DO. NOT. USE. PERSISTENCE. MODELS. AS. RETURN. OF. ACTIONS**. This is almost certain **NOT TO WORK** in any **non-trivial** operation (i.e. most simplest CRUD scenario)

Comment: you'll need to explain that one?... i'd also suggest you refrain from using capitals like that knobend