# Mapping POCO class which has a (one-to-one) reference to another POCO class with AutoMapper EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper

My apologies for (perhaps) not using the right terms in the title and this post. 
The problem is as follows: 
I have a POCO class which has a reference to another table (which is read only). This table has a one-to-one relationship with the other table.

I have set this upo as follow:

```
    public class Commodity
    {
        public Commodity()
        {
        }

        public long CommodityID { get; set; }

        public long CommodityMaterialID { get; set; }

        public decimal? SpecficWeight { get; set; }

        public OmsCommodityMaterial OmsCommodityMaterial { get; set; }

    }
```

The `OmsCommodityMaterial` property is the referenced table. This referenced table is also a POCO class which has some other fields, and a porperty back to my own (Commodity) table so I can make a one-to-one relationship with Fluent:

```
    public class OmsCommodityMaterial : OmsBaseClass
    {
        public OmsCommodityMaterial()
        {
        }

        public long? CommodityMaterialID { get; set; }

        public long? CommodityID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public long? SortOrder { get; set; }

        public Commodity Commodity { get; set; }
    }
```

Fluent (for the one-to-one relation) is set up as follows:

```
    public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {

        public virtual DbSet<Commodity> Commodity { get; set; }

        // Oms classes:
        public virtual DbSet<OmsCommodityMaterial> OmsCommodityMaterial { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
           : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Commodity>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.CommodityID)
                    .HasColumnName("CommodityID")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(e => e.CommodityMaterialID)
                    .HasColumnName("CommodityMaterialID");

                entity.Property(e => e.SpecficWeight)
                    .HasColumnName("SpecficWeight")
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)");

                entity.HasOne(a => a.OmsCommodityMaterial)
                    .WithOne(b => b.Commodity)
                    .HasForeignKey<Commodity>(b => b.CommodityMaterialID);
            });

        }
    }
```

In my endpoint I want to do a GET of all values which return the specific fields of my own table (Commodity) and all the fields of the referenced table (OmsCommodityMaterial).

For this purpose I created a ViewModel (also because else I get a circular reference as I found out in this post: [ERR_CONNECTION_RESET returning Async including object child collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44648707/err-connection-reset-returning-async-including-object-child-collections)) which looks as follow:

```
    public class CommodityViewModel
    {
        public long CommodityID { get; set; }

        public long CommodityMaterialID { get; set; }

        public decimal? SpecficWeight { get; set; }

        public OmsCommodityMaterial OmsCommodityMaterial { get; set; }
    }
```

For the `ViewModels` I am using `AutoMapper`, but I actually have no clue how I can map / return the list of the above ViewModel.

**UPDATE**

I ended up eliminating the Circular reference error by adding the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to the `public virtual Commodity Commodity { get; set; }` property in the `OmsCommodityMaterial` POCO class. Now I can get all the needed column values:

```
return await this.Context.Commodity
                .Include(i => i.OmsCommodityMaterial)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Though, I suppose this is not the way to go. There should be a better solution for this by creating a `ViewModel` that retrieves the Commodity columns and (some) of the referenced `OmsCommodityMaterial` columns without falling in the Circular Reference error, but how (using AutoMapper)?

Comment: After having look at [getting started](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) of Auto Mapper where do you stuck or which specific part do you don't understand?

Comment: If `OmsCommodityMaterial` should be lazy loaded by EF, you also have to make the property in `Commodity` `virtual`.