# Problem when I Try to return a query including a navigation property using an API Controller

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm writing my first API Controllers but I'm having problems when I try to include a navigation property, e.g.: when I make a query like

```
    public IEnumerable<Batch> GetByItemId(long itemId)
    {
         return context.Batch.Where(b => b.ItemId == itemId).ToArray();// It works 
    }
```

I get an expected result (using powershell):

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:5000/api/batch/10 -Method Get

id             : 50
creationDate   : 2018-11-04T00:46:05.665537
itemId         : 10
item           : 
expirationDate : 2019-01-16T00:00:00
batchLocations : 

id             : 65
creationDate   : 2018-11-04T01:30:54.492142
itemId         : 10
item           : 
expirationDate : 2019-01-01T00:00:00
batchLocations :
```

But when I try to include the BatchLocation navigation property:

```
    public IEnumerable<Batch> GetByItemId(long itemId)
    {
        return context.Batch
           .Where(b => b.ItemId == itemId)
           .Include(b => b.BatchLocations)
           .ToArray();
    }
```

The method GetByItemId returns the expected IEnumerable (I debugged it), but I get the following error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:5000/api/batch/10 -Method Get
Invoke-RestMethod : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:5000/api/batch/10 -Method Get
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod],     IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand


    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BatchController : Controller
    {
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public BatchController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IEnumerable<Batch> GetById(long id) => unitOfWork.Batchs.GetByItemId(id);
    }
```

The repository code:

```
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
      protected readonly AppDbContext context;
      public Repository(AppDbContext ctx) => context = ctx;
    }

    public class BatchRepository : Repository<Batch>, IBatchRepository
    {
      public BatchRepository(AppDbContext ctx) : base(ctx)
      {}
      public IEnumerable<Batch> GetByItemId(long itemId)
      {
        return context.Batch.Where(b => b.ItemId == itemId).Include(b => b.Item).ToArray();// Problem 
        // return context.Batch.Where(b => b.ItemId == itemId).ToArray();  //It works
      }
    }
```

Screenshot with debugging Info:

[Debugging Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qpkm.png)

When I try to use the Api Controller using React

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ItemInfo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { batchs: [] };
        this.renderBatchs = this.renderBatchs.bind(this);
        fetch('api/batch/'+this.props.itemId)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(batchInfo => {
                this.setState({ batchs: batchInfo });
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ', error.message);
        });;
    }

renderBatchs() {
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Id</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    {this.state.batchs.map((batch, index) => (
                        <tr key={index}><th>{batch.id}</th></tr>
                    ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        )
}

render() {
    const batchs = this.renderBatchs();
    return (
        <div>
            {batchs}
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ItemInfo;
```

I get the following console message:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/api/batch/1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
There has been a problem with your fetch operation:  Failed to fetch
```

And I don't know why, any suggestion or reference will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you getting your context in your repository method? Is it being injected?

Comment: I added aditional code, but I don't think the problem is there.

Comment: I doubt the issue is with the controller - I'd suspect an issue in your data model. If you havent tested your repository already, try writing a unit test to see if you can call the method directly. Then you'll either get a proper error message or at least prove that your data model is ok.

Comment: I added a screenshoot with the debugging info, I'm just learning but it looks Ok. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the error found using React I found this post [ERR_CONNECTION_RESET returning Async including object child collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44648707/err-connection-reset-returning-async-including-object-child-collections), that's the same problem with the same solution: I have navigation properties on both the Batch and the Item model, and I was returing a Persistence Model, I just didn't know this ["DO. NOT. USE. PERSISTENCE. MODELS. AS. RETURN. OF. ACTIONS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44648707/err-connection-reset-returning-async-including-object-child-collections#comment76288314_44648707). Then I created a ViewModel and everything is Ok.